# How to display a block of data a certain no. of times

Tags: javascript, foreach, fetch, slice

I'm displaying some data but at the moment each element is only being displayed once. I want this set of data to be displayed a certain number of times. How would I change my code or what would I use to get all of this data displayed a few times? I tried using slice to display it 4 times but it's only being displayed once.

```js
fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    var divElement = document.createElement('div');
    divElement.className = "text";
    data.slice(0, 4).forEach((div, i) => {
      divElement.innerHTML = ` <h2><strong>${data[i].name}</strong></h2>
    <p><strong>${data[i].summary}</strong></p>
    <p><strong>Genre: ${data[i].genres}</strong></p>
    <p><strong>Schedule: ${data[i].schedule.days} at ${data[i].schedule.time}</strong></p>
    <p><strong><a class="link" href=${data[i].url}>More Info</a></strong></p>
    `

      document.body.appendChild(divElement);
    })
  })

fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    var divElement = document.createElement('div')
    divElement.className = "image";
    data.slice(0, 4).forEach((div, i) => {
      divElement.innerHTML = ` <img src="${data[i].image.medium}"/>
    `

      document.body.appendChild(divElement);
    })
  })
```

```css
.text:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

img {
  padding-left: 160px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.text {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 40px 10px 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #747474;
  color: white;
}

.link {
  color: rgb(37, 180, 216);
}

.link:visited {
  color: white;
}

.text h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alatsi|Dancing+Script|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tv.css">
  <script src="tv.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Display the data in a loop `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { code to display data }`

Comment: `slice` doesn't display it 4 times, it just displays the first 4 elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're overwriting `divElement.innerHTML` each time through the `.forEach()` loop, and appending the same `divElement` to the DOM. `appendChild()` doesn't make a copy of the element; if it's already in the DOM, it gets moved to the new place.

You should concatenate the HTML to the `innerHTML` each time through the loop, and append the DIV to the body at the end.

Inside the `forEach()` loops, you can refer to the current element of the array using `div`, you don't need to index it as `data[i]`.

```js
fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    var divElement = document.createElement('div');
    divElement.className = "text";
    data.slice(0, 4).forEach((div) => {
      divElement.innerHTML += ` <h2><strong>${div.name}</strong></h2>
    <p><strong>${data[i].summary}</strong></p>
    <p><strong>Genre: ${div.genres}</strong></p>
    <p><strong>Schedule: ${div.schedule.days} at ${data[i].schedule.time}</strong></p>
    <p><strong><a class="link" href=${div.url}>More Info</a></strong></p>
    `;
    });
    document.body.appendChild(divElement);
  });

fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    var divElement = document.createElement('div')
    divElement.className = "image";
    data.slice(0, 4).forEach((div) => {
      divElement.innerHTML += ` <img src="${div.image.medium}"/>
    `
    })
    document.body.appendChild(divElement);
  })
```

```css
.text:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

img {
  padding-left: 160px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.text {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 40px 10px 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #747474;
  color: white;
}

.link {
  color: rgb(37, 180, 216);
}

.link:visited {
  color: white;
}

.text h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alatsi|Dancing+Script|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tv.css">
  <script src="tv.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: That's great, it worked! I now have a better understanding on how to retrieve data from an API and display it multiple times. Thank you very much. @Barmar

Comment: The only problem is that it's displaying the data hundreds of times rather than just 3 times like specified. Do you know why this is? @Barmar

Comment: It's displaying every element in the `data` array 4 times, like you said. So if the array has 100 items, you'll get 400 items in the output.

Comment: Sorry but I meant that I want to display the elements that I've already displayed on the screen four times, not all of the data. @Barmar

Comment: So you want to display the first 4 elements, and display each of them 4 times, for a total of 16? Then you can put back the `slice()`.

Comment: I wanted to just display each of the elements that I've retrieved four times instead of displaying each element once which is what I am currently doing e.g: I want  names of 4 different tv shows instead of the name of 1 tv show which I currently have. @Barmar

Comment: If there are 4 different shows and you want each one displayed 4 times, that's 16 total times. But I don't think that's what you really want. You want each one displayed once, instead of just one element displayed. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. This is closer to what I'm looking for as the image element is now displayed four times but I also want to display the other four paragraph elements four times each and display the h2 element four times too. At the moment, only the image is being displayed four times and I would like the other elements that I've retrieved and displayed once to be displayed four times too. @Barmar

Comment: I'm really getting lost. My original answer showed how to display the same things multiple times, but you said it was wrong. So I decided you were having trouble explaining what you wanted in English, and changed to what I guessed you wanted.

Comment: Any programmer should know how to do something repeatedly with a `for` loop, I shouldn't have to show that.

Comment: My answer uses the same method to display the image elements and the paragraph elements. I don't know why you're seeing something different for them.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to put the data.forEach (without the slice) inside a for loop. That's all